# How to return an empty object when methods are called reactively

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am calling two methods in reactive style.

```
Mono<OrderPublicDto> order = orderWebClient.getOrderById(orderID, bearerToken);
 
Mono<DriverDto> driver = order.flatMap(o -> vehicleWebClient.getDriverById(o.getDriverId(), bearerToken));
```

I need to make it so that if truckID from order (OrderPublicDto) == null, DriverDto empty is returned in the second method.

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `filter` operator to return an empty `Mono` in this scenario:

```java
orderWebClient.getOrderById(orderID, bearerToken)
    .filter(o -> o.getTruckID() != null)
    .flatMap(o -> vehicleWebClient.getDriverById(o.getDriverId(), bearerToken)));
```

Comment: hmmm. I don't think this is the correct solution.,

Comment: @AlexGrimaldo would you care to elaborate?